# Change background of an Accessory View in a UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) UITableViewCell consists of two sections:
[image]

I set a custom image for **Accessory View**:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("settingCell") as! SettingsTableViewCell
    cell.setCellColor(self.items[indexPath.row])
    let img = UIImage(named: "icon-right-arrow")!
    let imgView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    imgView.frame.size.width = img.size.width
    imgView.frame.size.height = img.size.height
    imgView.image = img
    imgView.image = imgView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    imgView.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    cell.accessoryView = imgView

    return cell
}
```

Function which get triggered when a cell is **selected**:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
    selectedCell.setSelectedColor()
    let img = UIImage(named: "icon-right-arrow")!
    let imgView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    imgView.frame.size.width = selectedCell.accessoryView!.frame.width
    imgView.frame.size.height = selectedCell.accessoryView!.frame.height
    imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    imgView.image = img
    imgView.image = imgView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    imgView.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    selectedCell.accessoryView = imgView

    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

}
```

And for **deselected** cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
    selectedCell.setDeSelectedColor()
    let img = UIImage(named: "icon-right-arrow")!
    let imgView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    imgView.frame.size.width = selectedCell.accessoryView!.frame.width
    imgView.frame.size.height = selectedCell.accessoryView!.frame.height
    imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    imgView.image = img
    imgView.image = imgView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    imgView.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    selectedCell.accessoryView = imgView

}
```

But the result is not what I want, Accessory View still has a gray background but I want it be orange:

[image]

Comment: As you change the background for selected cell your-self, you can set the selection style to None instead of gray or blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set deselected cell selectionStyle to None with `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
    selectedCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    selectedCell.setDeSelectedColor()
    let img = UIImage(named: "icon-right-arrow")!
    let imgView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    imgView.frame.size.width = selectedCell.accessoryView!.frame.width
    imgView.frame.size.height = selectedCell.accessoryView!.frame.height
    imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    imgView.image = img
    imgView.image = imgView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    imgView.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    selectedCell.accessoryView = imgView

}
```

Comment: `selectedCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` should be set before `selectedCell.contentView.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()`

Comment: and i guess selectedCell.setDeSelectedColor() this is not useful?